# How to fake indirectly called functions of a Typescript namespace?

Tags: typescript, mocking, mocha.js, sinon

Assume the following namespace is given:

```
export namespace CodeUnderTest {
    export function A(): void {
        B();
    }

    export function B(): void {
        console.log("B was called.");
    }
}
```

How do I write a test that calls `A()` with a fake implementation of `B()`?

Here is how I tried to do it with Sinon:

```
import * as sinon from 'sinon';
import { CodeUnderTest } from './code-under-test';

describe('CodeUnderTest', () => {
    it('calls fake', () => {
        sinon.replace(CodeUnderTest, 'B', () => {
            console.log("Fake was called.");
        });

        CodeUnderTest.A();
    });
})
```

When I run it with `mocha -r ts-node/register code-under-test.spec.ts` the test prints `B was called.` I'd expect it to print `Fake was called.`

I'm open to any solution, not just ones implemented with Sinon.

Comment: If you'll look at generated [code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=export%20namespace%20CodeUnderTest%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20function%20A()%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20B()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20function%20B()%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22B%20was%20called.%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D) `A` use direct reference to `B` and not to namespace member (`CodeUnderTest .B`). So when you replace it with fake, `A` is not affected